# Transferring an object via REST

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I've been trying to send an object from one application to another using rest.

Sender:

```
@Controller
public class Sender {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/comMessageApp-api/getMessages")
    public String restGetMessages() {
        String url = "http://localhost:8079/comMessageApp-api/responseMessages";
        HttpEntity<Dto2> entity = new HttpEntity<>(new Dto2());
        ResponseEntity<Dto2> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Dto2.class);
    }
}
```

Receiver:

```
@RestController
public class Receiver {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/comMessageApp-api/responseMessages")
    public void restResponseMessages(HttpEntity<Dto2> request) {
        System.out.println(request.getBody());       
    }
}
```

DTO:

```
public class Dto2 {
    private String string = "Test string";

    public Dto2() {
    }

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```

Jackson is used serialization/deserialization.

Any ideas, why request.getBody() printed in the Receiver is null???
I tried to send the object inside HttpEntity and inside RequestEntity. No success in both cases. On the receiving side I always get null.

Comment: If you are trying to send the DTO to the receiver then you should be using a POST method instead of GET.  GET is for retrieving data from the other side.  If you want to retrieve the DTO from the Receiver then you need to create the DTO in the Receiver and return that.

Comment: I have changed it to post. But now I get 'org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 null' exception on the Sender side. The request never reaches Receiver

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In this case, you probably need to show to minimal, complete programs: one for the server and one for the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sender (client) side is very close but your server side doesn't return a value so change the type to Void:

```
ResponseEntity<Void> response = restOps.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Void.class);
```

Your receiver (server) side is not quite set up correctly either, you need to set the HTTP method to [edited] POST.  You'll also need to tell Spring to map the body of the request (your rest payload) onto the parameter;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/comMessageApp-api/responseMessages", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void recieveDto (@RequestBody final Dto dto) {
    System.out.println(dto.toString());
}
```

[EDIT] Brainfart, the http method should be set to POST on receive annotation.

[Further suggestion]
403 errors may be due to Spring Security, if you have it switched on (check your POM if you're not sure) try this;

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
        .authorizeRequests().
            antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }
}
```

You'll want to be tightening up security once you know it works.

Comment: Doesn't work. 'HttpMethod.POST' generates 'org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 null' on Sender side

Comment: Strange - 403 is a forbidden message code, are you using Spring Security in your application?

Comment: Thanks for reminding about Spring Security. Yes, I use it and I completely forgot that csrf protection needs to be disabled. Now rest works

Answer (score -1):

try to use `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")`

Comment: Why should they try that? What does it accomplish differently? Why do you think so? What was the issue in their original code? Your answer is pretty useless without those details.